# Zombienet: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed

Tags: frontier, zombienet

I was trying to deploy Ethereum smart contracts to my parachain as part of a Zombienet test... After deploying a bunch of contracts including demo,
BoxU, ERC1820, ERC20, ERC721, ERC1155, ERC777, ERC4626, ERC20Upgradeable, ERC721Upgradeable. Then when Zombienet was trying to deploy ERC1155Upgradeable, it got stuck at this line: `tx = await tokenU.deployed()`. See the deployment code below:

```
    const TokenU = await ethers.getContractFactory(tokenCtrtNameU);
    log1("checkpoint 2");
    const tokenU = await upgrades.deployProxy(TokenU, ERC1155Arg, { initializer: "initialize" });
    log1("checkpoint 3");
    tx = await tokenU.deployed();
```

Then I use this command to see what was going on in the collator:

```
tail -f  /tmp/zombie-21376e2e46cad37d1c90b10d38ca14f3_-8552-iVEWz3ZX31I8/collator01.log
```

Then I saw this error:

```
2022-09-01 21:09:42.039  WARN tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain] Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0x33535f - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x4f06 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h6a371c04dcf7739e
    2: 0x4ec7 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic::h9bf88698387979d4
    3: 0x196d9f - <unknown>!<hero_runtime::FindAuthorAdapter<F> as frame_support::traits::validation::FindAuthor<primitive_types::H160>>::find_author::hb75087d0ff50d58a
    4: 0x2cfaf1 - <unknown>!pallet_evm::<impl pallet_evm::pallet::Pallet<T>>::find_author::hc0ba43b18d98715f
    5: 0x123657 - <unknown>!<(TupleElement0,TupleElement1) as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::h8c02df61507e22df
    6: 0x125856 - <unknown>!<(TupleElement0,TupleElement1) as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::hacec8aa069fcdecf
    7: 0x176ccc - <unknown>!<(TupleElement0,TupleElement1) as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::h32e12ed50e5008ad
    8: 0x2db235 - <unknown>!<(TupleElement0,TupleElement1) as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::h2c719d04a10b76ff
    9: 0x240c79 - <unknown>!<(TupleElement0,TupleElement1) as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::h2f55e682c72fcce1
   10: 0x14f1a3 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::finalize_block::h0f119abaaa10d4a4
   11: 0xa3625 - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_finalize_block
```

Those scripts work fine when I was using them to deploy smart contracts on Hardhat's virtual EVM and on my natively built collator EVM(running with 2 validators in Bash)

What went wrong?
Maybe I need to slow down the deployment?
Or Zombienet cannot handle heavy contract deployment?

Or Zombienet cannot handle high traffic RPC calls?

Comment: Hi @Russo, that error is from the wasm execution and is not related to zombienet. Are you using k8s? Does the image have the same binary that you run locally?

Comment: Hi @pepoviola, I am using native binaries. I think wasm cannot handle too many deployment...